# How do I pass a list in url for a REST api?

Tags: rest, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I am trying to pass a list of IDs to a REST api (apex ords).

I have a url like this :

```
https://apex.oracle.com/***/apex/anime_keeper/ak/getAnimeList/:ids
```

when I do :

```
https://apex.oracle.com/***/apex/anime_keeper/ak/getAnimeList/1
```

I get the item with id = 1 but if I do :

```
https://apex.oracle.com/***/apex/anime_keeper/ak/getAnimeList/1,2,3
```

I get a 500 Internal Server Error

How should I format my url so I can use the 1,2,3 list in a `where id in (ids)` in apex ords?

this is a screenshot of ords if it can help :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That SQL won't work becase ORDS does not split the csv values out. So that sql as-is will be checking for `id in ( '1,2,3')` not `id in ( 1,2,3)`

There's multiple ways to accomplish what the intent is.

For example, using XMLTABLE

```
SELECT rownum,object_id
  FROM user_objects
 WHERE rownum IN (
   select (column_value).getstringval() csv_values
        FROM   
     xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(:ids, ',', '","')|| '"'))
 )
```

There are other ways mentioned here:
   [Using the "IN" clause with a comma delimited string from the output of a replace() function in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672545/using-the-in-clause-with-a-comma-delimited-string-from-the-output-of-a-replace)

Here's an ORDS REST API doing exactly what you intend.
[image]

Comment: I know I shouldn't be asking that but can you help me on that question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455756/how-to-make-a-post-request-with-ords ?

Answer (score 0):

In a URL, comma ',' has special meaning/purpose. It is to separate query arguments in url e.g

```
https://test.me/mypage?firstname=jon,lastname=doe,gender=m
```

So server is throwing 500 error as it finds corrupted or incomplete key/value pairs. It expects key=value pair after each comma.  To get around this we need to urlencode value e.g

```
https://apex.oracle.com/***/apex/anime_keeper/ak/getAnimeList/1%2C2%2C3
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I now understand URL encryption, but I still have a 500 error with that new URL, got any idea on the problem?