# How to make a POST request with ORDS?

Tags: sql, json, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I want to insert a new item with a POST request in ORDS application express.

I created my handler like this :

[image]

Then with android studio, I use volley to create a JSONObject (& the request at the same time) :

```
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
jsonBody.put("name", name);
jsonBody.put("genres", genres);
jsonBody.put("season", season);
jsonBody.put("episodes", nb_episodes);
jsonBody.put("rating", "0");
final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
```

I also tried this request with postman :

[image]

As you can see, I get a error 500 and I can't find the problem. If I do the query in SQL command, it works fine :

```
Insert into android_anime (name, genres, season, nb_episode, rating)
Values ('anime5', 'G6', 2, 24, 5)
```

What should I do to make my post request work?

edit

here's the table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE  "ANDROID_ANIME" 
(   "ID" NUMBER, 
"NAME" VARCHAR2(30), 
"GENRES" VARCHAR2(30), 
"SEASON" NUMBER, 
"NB_EPISODE" NUMBER, 
"RATING" NUMBER, 
 CONSTRAINT "ANDROID_ANIME_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
USING INDEX  ENABLE
)
```

Comment: Can you update this with the table definition?

Comment: for your POST, you need to define the parameters as well. So in ORDS you'd run ORDS.DEFINE_PARAMETER(
      p_module_name        => 'anime',
      p_pattern            => 'postAnime',
      p_method             => 'POST',
      p_name               => 'name',
      p_bind_variable_name => 'name',
      p_source_type        => 'HEADER',
      p_param_type         => 'STRING',
      p_access_method      => 'IN',
      p_comments           => NULL);    

then in your POST HEADER, you'd have a NAME value, then you could reference via :NAME in the INSERT code.

Comment: I withdraw said comment, only needed of passing on the header not the body...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess of the table definition.

```
SQL> create table android_anime(
  2  name varchar2(200),
  3  genres varchar2(200),
  4  season number,
  5  nb_episode number,
  6* rating number);

Table ANDROID_ANIME created.
```

Never used Volley but here's basic cUrl

```
## anime-lowercase
curl -X "POST" "https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/dbtools/test/postAnime" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d $'{
  "genres": "G6",
  "season": "1",
  "name": "anime-99",
  "nb_episode": "1",
  "rating": "1"
}'
```

The definition of the rest.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help, I realised looking at what you did that I did the beginners mistake and I am quite ashamed, I forgot the ; at the values line